# does anodizing aluminum change its reflectivity at 532nm

Tags: laser

Does anodizing aluminum change its reflectivity at 532nm?
I have tested percent reflection of highly polished aluminum at 532nm.
I am concerned that the aluminum will oxidize and change reflection percentage over time.
If I anodize the reflective surface will the percent reflection increase or decrease or remain the same.

Comment: Aluminum exposed to air will have an oxide layer on the surface. This oxide layer is self-limiting, so it will rapidly stabilize. Anodizing drives this reaction further. Since anodizing is not used on optical quality aluminum mirrors, one can surmise that it is not good for high quality mirrors.

Comment: You may wish to contact the researchers at the [Palomar Observatory](http://www.astro.caltech.edu/palomar/) in California, USA. The 200 inch Hale telescope uses an aluminum-coated primary mirror, so they should have some useful information on this topic. Part of routine maintenance is to strip and replace the aluminum on the mirror. But I'm not sure if that's related to oxidation, or other sources of surface contamination.

Answer (score 1):

Optical properties of aluminum, and it's various surface treatments and coatings are [readily available.](http://www.edmundoptics.com/resources/application-notes/optics/metallic-mirror-coatings/); these are from Edmumd Optics:

[image]

[Bare aluminum](http://rmico.com/bare-aluminum) will slowly oxidize, reducing the reflectance significantly for some wavelengths, and increasing surface scattering for others.

[This paper](http://krex.k-state.edu/dspace/handle/2097/15173) describes a number of anodization process parameters, and provides experimental results on specular reflection at 660 nm.  Results from p. 28 include a mirror (95%), some un-anodized, polished aluminum (60% +), with the anodized results on the following pages, with 20% specular reflectivity the highest value reported.

I would expect similar results at 532 nm, mostly due to the increased surface scattering.